# Working on Same Firebase Account from Different Computer (Different PC)

Tags: java, android, firebase, authentication, sha

I'm trying to use a firebase android studio project on a different computer and it wont work the register functionality is broken but when I use it on the orignal it works fine.

From googling people are saying that I need to add the sha1 from the project to the firebase console I tried this but still no luck any suggestions as I have no idea what to do now

Comment: "won't work the register functionality is broken" doesn't provide enough information so we can help. What exactly doesn't work? Do you have any errors?

Comment: @AlexMamo The App register functionality is basically code which allows a user to register and be added to the firebase realtime database it works perfectly on my computer at home but as soon as I try importing the project to my laptop the app will run but as soon as I try to register a user it doesnt work and it gives no errors

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.